# How to debug error "A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, debugging, ef-database-first

My question is **how to debug the error "Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values." when working with Database-First approach ?**

How to find out which entities caused the errors ?

What to specificaly look for in the `DB Schema` when you receive this error and doesn't know from which table it comes from ? I'm in a scenario where I have hundreds of tables in the Database that I've just added into the `EF DB Diagram`.

Visual Studio will give an `inner exception` with this message and `error code -2146232022` but no pointers at the entity that broke validation.

Context :

- EF 6.0 (Database First)
- MS-SQL 2014
- C#
- Obviously this error is triggered on `model.SaveChanges()`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After trying the SQL Server Profiler, I have seen that despite of the fact that error is supposedly sent by the Database's Core validation system, no query was being run on the SQL server at the moment of the `model.SaveChanges()`.
Therefore it could only be a problem with the foreign keys, EF6 trying to generate a foreign key that couldn't exist.

I found the error after checking every single foreign key on SQL. One of them was mistakenly defined on anotherr databse field. After changing to it to the right field, everything saved again.